# Find all possible paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, path, breadth-first-search

Hi for school i have to make an assigment. I have to implement an algorithm that prints all possible paths from a given destination and source. Now i have stumbled upon an error, which i quite frankly do not know how to solve. Should i just start with a new search? Or?...If anybody could help me out, that would be awesome :). I have provide my code, the example input and output, as well as my error message below. I was trying to debug it with print statements, but i am just getting more confused.

EDIT, some more information about the structure of the input

The program takes as input the ids of the start and end nodes of type unsigned int separated by a

```
     ->.
```

In a new line the data-set of the graph nodes and the nodes they are following where all the ids are of type unsigned int.

```
 (i.e. id1 follows id1,1 and id1,2 meaning you have the directed edges (id1, id1,1) and (id1, id1,2))

                    <idstart>-><idend>\n
 <id1>, <id1,1>, <id1,2>, ...; ...; <idn>, <idn,1>, <idn,2>. . . \n
```

The expected output is the path from the start to the end node.

```
<idstart>->...-><idend>\n
```

The Input:

```
1->5
1, 2, 3; 2, 3; 3, 4; 4, 5; 5, 1
```

So here the start node is 1 and the end node is 5, the edges are (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5) (5,1)

The Output:

```
 1->2->3->4->5
 1->3->4->5
```

My Output and error message:

```
   paths = print_paths(adj1, vertices, src, dest)
   File "\\asg.local\echnaton\HOME-MED\e.brands\Desktop\task-2.py", line 122, in 
   print_paths
   bfs(adj1, parent, n, start)
   File "\\asg.local\echnaton\HOME-MED\e.brands\Desktop\task-2.py", line 89, in bfs
   for v in adj1[u]:
   IndexError: list index out of range

   Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my code!

```
from sys import maxsize
from typing import List

from collections import defaultdict, deque


def add_edge(adj: List[List[int]],
             src: int, dest: int) -> None:
    print(adj, src, dest)
    adj[src].append(dest)
    adj[dest].append(src) #haalt 5 niet


def stringify_path(path: List):
    '''
    Build string to print
    '''
    ret = ''
    for id in path[:-1]:
        ret = f'{ret}{id}->'
    try:
        ret = f'{ret}{path[-1]}'
    except IndexError:
        pass

    return ret


def output(paths: List[List]):
    '''
    Prints all paths from the list in param
    '''
    paths_string = []
    for p in paths:
        paths_string.append(stringify_path(p))
    print(*paths_string, sep='\n')


'''
DO NOT CHANGE ABOVE
'''


def find_paths(paths: List[List[int]], path: List[int],
               parent: List[List[int]], n: int, u: int) -> None:
    # Base Case
    if (u == -1):
        paths.append(path.copy())
        return

    # Loop for all the parents
    # of the given vertex
    for par in parent[u]:
        # Insert the current
        # vertex in path
        path.append(u)

        # Recursive call for its parent
        find_paths(paths, path, parent, n, par)

        # Remove the current vertex
        path.pop()


# Function which performs bfs
# from the given source vertex
def bfs(adj1: List[List[int]],
        parent: List[List[int]], n: int,
        start: int) -> None:
    # dist will contain shortest distance
    # from start to every other vertex
    dist = [maxsize for _ in range(n)]
    q = deque()

    # Insert source vertex in queue and make
    # its parent -1 and distance 0
    q.append(start)
    print(q)
    parent[start] = [-1]
    print(parent)
    dist[start] = 0
    print(dist)

    # Until Queue is empty
    while q:
        u = q[0]
        print(u)
        q.popleft()
        for v in adj1[u]:
            print(v, adj1[u])
            print(dist[v], dist[u])
            if (dist[v] > dist[u] + 1):
                #print(dist[v], dist[u])

                # A shorter distance is found
                # So erase all the previous parents
                # and insert new parent u in parent[v]
                dist[v] = dist[u] + 1
                q.append(v)
                print(q)
                parent[v].clear()
                print(parent)
                parent[v].append(u)
                print(parent)

            elif (dist[v] == dist[u] + 1):

                # Another candidate parent for
                # shortes path found
                parent[v].append(u)


# Function which prints all the paths
# from start to end
def print_paths(adj1: List[List[int]], n: int,
                start: int, end: int) -> None:
    paths = []
    path = []
    parent = [[] for _ in range(n)]

    # Function call to bfs
    bfs(adj1, parent, n, start)

    # Function call to find_paths
    find_paths(paths, path, parent, n, end)
    for v in paths:

        # Since paths contain each
        # path in reverse order,
        # so reverse it
        v = reversed(v)

        # Print node for the current path
        for u in v:
            print(u, end=" ")
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    '''
    Fetch starting and target node.
    '''
    start, target = [int(x) for x in input().split('->')]

    '''
    Fetch `;` separated twitter data. <id-1: str>, <follower_1-2: str>, ..<follower_1-2: str>; ... 
    i.e: 1, 2, 3; 2, 3, 1; 3, 2
    '''
    data = input()
    data = data.split('; ')
    graph = dict()
    edges_list = []
    for d in data:
        parts = d.split(',')
        if len(parts) > 1:
            id = parts[0]
            id = id.strip()

            followers = parts[1:]
            followers = [x.strip() for x in followers if x.strip()]
            # print(followers)
            for f in followers:
                if f == '':
                    # node is not following other nodes.
                    continue
                edge = int(id), int(f)

                # print(edge)

                edges_list.append(edge)

    print(edges_list)
    vertices = len(edges_list) + 1
    print(vertices)
    adj = [[] for _ in range(vertices)]
    for i in edges_list:
        print(i)
        print(adj)
        node_1 = i[0]
        print(node_1)
        node_2 = i[1]
        print(node_2)
        add_edge(adj, node_1, node_2)
        print(adj)

    src = edges_list[0][0]
    dest = vertices - 1
    adj1 = [x for x in adj if x != []]
    print(adj1)
    paths = print_paths(adj1, vertices, src, dest)
    print(paths)



    '''
    Print the paths.
    '''
    # output(paths)

    '''
    TODO: Step 3: Call your 'find_paths` function with the parameters you defined.
    '''
    #paths: List[List] = find_paths()

    '''
    Print the paths.
    '''
    #output(paths)
```

Ps do not mind the additional (printing) functions, now i am just focused on making the algorithm work!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the task you've been given, when you say path, do you mean the numbers between 1 and 5? The second line of your example inputs, could you elaborate on which of the 2 examples, either the first or second line, you'll be consuming?

Comment: @DavidS sorry i was a bit unclear, i have edited the question. Is it now more clear?